# MVC Controller: Using LINQ to check for duplicate value already existing in table before Save?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following `Create() - POST` controller for my `Manufacturers` entity:

```
// POST: INV_Manufacturers/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,manufacturer_description,created_date,created_by,modified_date,modified_by")] INV_Manufacturers iNV_Manufacturers)
{

    iNV_Manufacturers.created_date = DateTime.Now;
    iNV_Manufacturers.created_by = System.Environment.UserName;

    if (ModelState.IsValid == false && iNV_Manufacturers.Id == 0)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.INV_Manufacturers.Add(iNV_Manufacturers);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(iNV_Manufacturers);
}
```

The `Model` is defined thus:

```
public class INV_Manufacturers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Manufacturer.")]
    public string manufacturer_description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string created_by { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

    public string modified_by { get; set; }
}
```

What is the syntax using `LINQ` in my controller where I can search the `INV_Manufacturers` table and check if a `Manufacturer` with the same `description` already exists in the table as compared with the value that is about to be saved in my `Create()` method?

**PSEUDOCODE**:

```
if (manufacturer.description == ANY.manufacturer.description in Table)
{
    alert("This value already exists in table!");
} else {
    Save(new manufacturer);
}
```

Comment: In addition to Travis' answer for server side checking, you can also use a `[Remote]` attribute if you want client side validation as well. [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just use `.Any()`. It will return a boolean depending on if the entity was found. Upon the first instance of finding it will stop enumerating so it will break out fast if it exists. If it does not exist, it will have checked the whole table, and will return false (which is why the `Add` is in `!.Any()`)

```
if(!db.INV_Manufacturers.Any(m => m.manufacturer_description == iNV_Manufacturers.manufacturer_description))
{
    db.INV_Manufacturers.Add(iNV_Manufacturers);
}
else
{
    //logic for when that description exists
    //for example, to add to ModelState
    ModelState.AddModelError("manufacturer_description","Description Exists");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Travis! Any tips on *(when description exists)* posting such a message back to the View?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic It depends on where this code resides. There are many ways to accomplish that task. You can place it in the ModelState dictionary and invalidate the description forcing the user to change it, you can simply state there was an error, you can send back a detailed error message as part of the view model, you can use ajax to test first in the view prior to submitting and then provide the information that way, you can use TempData to place a string indicating the error and look for TempData in the view, and probably still more options. Go with what makes sense in your apps scope :)

Comment: Hmm... well I'm in my controller. Do you have an example of placing into the `ModelState - dictionary` and invalidating the description? That sounds like an interesting route to try.